# Button in Graphic

Tags: java, button, graphics, awt, paint

My last question was probably to long so I decide to change it 
I looking for way to make button or listener that make this graphics shows after pressing I just starting with programming so I don't know how to do it exactly. 
Any help will be appreciated:)

```
 import java.applet.Applet; 
import java.awt.*; 

 //The applet code
 public class Main extends Applet {

     /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * 
     */


    public void init() {  
            setSize(2000,500);  
        }  

     public void paint(Graphics g) {    
    int A = 0;





//Hat
             g.setColor(Color.blue);
             int m[] = {A+170,A+120,A+220};
             int hat[] = {0,35,35};
             int pts = 3;
             g.fillPolygon(m, hat, pts);       
//head
             g.setColor(Color.gray); 
             g.fillRoundRect(123,35,95,95,20,20);   
//Eye one
             g.setColor(Color.blue); 
             g.fillOval(130,50,25,25);
//Eye (inside) one
             g.setColor(Color.black); 
             g.fillOval(137,57,10,10);
//Eyelid right
             g.setColor(Color.cyan); 
             g.fillArc(130,50,26,15,-15,220);   
//Eye two 
             g.setColor(Color.blue); 
             g.fillOval(185,50,25,25);
//Eye (inside)two 
             g.setColor(Color.black); 
             g.fillOval(192,57,10,10);  
//Eyelid left
             g.setColor(Color.cyan); 
             g.fillArc(184,50,26,15,-15,220);   
//Nose
             g.setColor(Color.green); 
             g.fillRoundRect(165,70,10,25,20,20);
//Mouth
             g.setColor(Color.red); 
             g.fillArc(140,90,60,40,20,-220);
//Mouth (inside fill out)
             g.setColor(Color.white); 
             g.fillArc(142,99,55,26,20,-220);   
//Mouth (inside2 middle1)
             g.setColor(Color.red); 
             g.drawArc(142,97,55,20,20,-220); 
//Mouth (inside3 middle2)
             g.setColor(Color.red); 
             g.drawArc(142,98,55,20,20,-220); 
//Neck
             g.setColor(Color.gray); 
             g.fillRect(155,130,30,20);
//Body 
             g.setColor(Color.gray); 
             g.fillRoundRect(100,151,145,70,20,20);
//Body 2 
             g.setColor(Color.gray); 
             g.fillRoundRect(120,185,100,100,20,20);
//Chest 1 (left)
             g.setColor(Color.black); 
             g.fillRoundRect(107,157,60,50,20,20);  
//Chest 2 (right)
             g.setColor(Color.black); 
             g.fillRoundRect(178,157,60,50,20,20);  
//Abs 1 (left)
             g.setColor(Color.black); 
             g.fillRoundRect(140,209,30,22,20,20);  
//Abs 2 (left)
             g.setColor(Color.black); 
             g.fillRoundRect(140,233,30,22,20,20);  
//Abs 3 (left)
             g.setColor(Color.black); 
             g.fillRoundRect(140,257,30,22,20,20);
//Abs 1 (right)
             g.setColor(Color.black); 
             g.fillRoundRect(174,209,30,22,20,20);  
//Abs 2 (right)
             g.setColor(Color.black); 
             g.fillRoundRect(174,233,30,22,20,20);  
//Abs 3 (right)
             g.setColor(Color.black); 
             g.fillRoundRect(174,257,30,22,20,20);
//Arm 1 
             g.setColor(Color.gray); 
             g.fillRoundRect(45,151,50,130,20,20);  
//Hand 1 
             g.setColor(Color.black); 
             g.fillRoundRect(45,250,50,30,20,20);
//Gun top hole
             g.setColor(Color.red); 
             g.fillOval(55,260,30,30);        
//Gun 1 
             g.setColor(Color.blue); 
             g.fillRoundRect(60,270,20,60,20,20);        
//Gun end 
             g.setColor(Color.black); 
             g.fillRect(60,320,20,10);
//Fire 
             g.setColor(Color.red); 
             g.fillOval(63,330,14,40);
//Arm 2
             g.setColor(Color.gray); 
             g.fillRoundRect(250,151,50,130,20,20);
//Hand 2 
             g.setColor(Color.black); 
             g.fillRoundRect(250,250,50,30,20,20);       
//Saw top hole
             g.setColor(Color.red); 
             g.fillOval(260,260,30,30);
//Saw stick
             g.setColor(Color.black); 
             g.fillRoundRect(270,270,10,60,20,20);
//Saw teeth 1
             g.setColor(Color.gray);
             g.fillRect(256,311,38,38);
//Saw teeth 2
             g.setColor(Color.red);
             int a[] = {A+250,A+275,A+300,A+275};
             int saw[] = {330,305,330,355};
             int fourPoints = 4;
             g.fillPolygon(a, saw, fourPoints);    
//Saw middle wheel 
             g.setColor(Color.black);
             g.fillOval(257,312,37,37);
//Saw middle wheel end
             g.setColor(Color.gray);
             g.fillOval(267,322,16,16);
//Pants 
             g.setColor(Color.black); 
             g.fillRect(120,284,101,50);
//Leg 1
             g.setColor(Color.gray); 
             g.fillRoundRect(115,335,50,150,20,20);
//Leg 2 
             g.setColor(Color.gray); 
             g.fillRoundRect(181,335,50,150,20,20);
//feet1
             g.setColor(Color.black); 
             g.fillRoundRect(115,460,50,30,20,20);
//feet2 
             g.setColor(Color.black); 
             g.fillRoundRect(181,460,50,30,20,20);
     }
 }
```

Comment: I'd suggest changing your logic.  Create a custom component extending from something like `JPanel`, override it's `paintComponent` method and place your custom graphics within it.  Create a `JButton` and place it on the screen along with another `JPanel`.  When the button is clicked either replace the blank panel with your custom one or add it to it. See [How to Use Buttons, Check Boxes, and Radio Buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) for more details

Comment: I just start doing java and our teacher show us simple graphics creations like rectangle, ovals etc. So I decide to us it for something bigger that just simple shape and make this robot. Full version have over 1000 lines and robot is moving. I was thinking create classes for each shape to make code shorter. But I did not have time with all other assignments so I just keep it like that.

Comment: You might be interested in [2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/) and the [Shape API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/geometry/index.html)

Comment: 1) Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/). 2) Why use AWT?   See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6255106/java-gui-listeners-without-awt/6255978#6255978) for many good reasons to abandon AWT using components in favor of Swing.

Comment: @TomaszLesiecki do not forget to select the correct answer. And good luck with your coding. Graphics is not my forte as of yet, but I hope that I manged to give you some help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by at least using the Swing API.  I'd also question the need to use applets and would recommend using window based classes instead, they are whole lot simpler to deal with.

Start by creating a custom component extending from something like `JPanel`, override it's `paintComponent` method and place you custom painting within.

Create another `JPanel` and assign it a `BorderLayout` and add this to your main container, this will act as a place holder for the "robot pane"

Create a `JButton`, using a `BorderLayout`, place both the "content pane" and button in the top level container (in your case, the applet)

Attach an `ActionListener` to the button, when it is triggered, create a new instance of the "robot pane" and place it within the "content pane"

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JApplet;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Main extends JApplet {

    private JPanel content;

    public void init() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        content = new JPanel(new BorderLayout()) {
            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(500, 2000);
            }
        };
        add(content);

        JButton btn = new JButton("Show me the robot");
        add(btn, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                btn.setEnabled(false);
                RobotPane botPane = new RobotPane();
                content.add(botPane);
                revalidate();
                repaint();
            }
        });
    }

    public class RobotPane extends JPanel {

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(500, 2000);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            int A = 0;

//Hat
            g.setColor(Color.blue);
            int m[] = {A + 170, A + 120, A + 220};
            int hat[] = {0, 35, 35};
            int pts = 3;
            g.fillPolygon(m, hat, pts);
//head
            g.setColor(Color.gray);
            g.fillRoundRect(123, 35, 95, 95, 20, 20);
//Eye one
            g.setColor(Color.blue);
            g.fillOval(130, 50, 25, 25);
//Eye (inside) one
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.fillOval(137, 57, 10, 10);
//Eyelid right
            g.setColor(Color.cyan);
            g.fillArc(130, 50, 26, 15, -15, 220);
//Eye two 
            g.setColor(Color.blue);
            g.fillOval(185, 50, 25, 25);
//Eye (inside)two 
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.fillOval(192, 57, 10, 10);
//Eyelid left
            g.setColor(Color.cyan);
            g.fillArc(184, 50, 26, 15, -15, 220);
//Nose
            g.setColor(Color.green);
            g.fillRoundRect(165, 70, 10, 25, 20, 20);
//Mouth
            g.setColor(Color.red);
            g.fillArc(140, 90, 60, 40, 20, -220);
//Mouth (inside fill out)
            g.setColor(Color.white);
            g.fillArc(142, 99, 55, 26, 20, -220);
//Mouth (inside2 middle1)
            g.setColor(Color.red);
            g.drawArc(142, 97, 55, 20, 20, -220);
//Mouth (inside3 middle2)
            g.setColor(Color.red);
            g.drawArc(142, 98, 55, 20, 20, -220);
//Neck
            g.setColor(Color.gray);
            g.fillRect(155, 130, 30, 20);
//Body 
            g.setColor(Color.gray);
            g.fillRoundRect(100, 151, 145, 70, 20, 20);
//Body 2 
            g.setColor(Color.gray);
            g.fillRoundRect(120, 185, 100, 100, 20, 20);
//Chest 1 (left)
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.fillRoundRect(107, 157, 60, 50, 20, 20);
//Chest 2 (right)
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.fillRoundRect(178, 157, 60, 50, 20, 20);
//Abs 1 (left)
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.fillRoundRect(140, 209, 30, 22, 20, 20);
//Abs 2 (left)
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.fillRoundRect(140, 233, 30, 22, 20, 20);
//Abs 3 (left)
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.fillRoundRect(140, 257, 30, 22, 20, 20);
//Abs 1 (right)
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.fillRoundRect(174, 209, 30, 22, 20, 20);
//Abs 2 (right)
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.fillRoundRect(174, 233, 30, 22, 20, 20);
//Abs 3 (right)
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.fillRoundRect(174, 257, 30, 22, 20, 20);
//Arm 1 
            g.setColor(Color.gray);
            g.fillRoundRect(45, 151, 50, 130, 20, 20);
//Hand 1 
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.fillRoundRect(45, 250, 50, 30, 20, 20);
//Gun top hole
            g.setColor(Color.red);
            g.fillOval(55, 260, 30, 30);
//Gun 1 
            g.setColor(Color.blue);
            g.fillRoundRect(60, 270, 20, 60, 20, 20);
//Gun end 
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.fillRect(60, 320, 20, 10);
//Fire 
            g.setColor(Color.red);
            g.fillOval(63, 330, 14, 40);
//Arm 2
            g.setColor(Color.gray);
            g.fillRoundRect(250, 151, 50, 130, 20, 20);
//Hand 2 
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.fillRoundRect(250, 250, 50, 30, 20, 20);
//Saw top hole
            g.setColor(Color.red);
            g.fillOval(260, 260, 30, 30);
//Saw stick
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.fillRoundRect(270, 270, 10, 60, 20, 20);
//Saw teeth 1
            g.setColor(Color.gray);
            g.fillRect(256, 311, 38, 38);
//Saw teeth 2
            g.setColor(Color.red);
            int a[] = {A + 250, A + 275, A + 300, A + 275};
            int saw[] = {330, 305, 330, 355};
            int fourPoints = 4;
            g.fillPolygon(a, saw, fourPoints);
//Saw middle wheel 
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.fillOval(257, 312, 37, 37);
//Saw middle wheel end
            g.setColor(Color.gray);
            g.fillOval(267, 322, 16, 16);
//Pants 
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.fillRect(120, 284, 101, 50);
//Leg 1
            g.setColor(Color.gray);
            g.fillRoundRect(115, 335, 50, 150, 20, 20);
//Leg 2 
            g.setColor(Color.gray);
            g.fillRoundRect(181, 335, 50, 150, 20, 20);
//feet1
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.fillRoundRect(115, 460, 50, 30, 20, 20);
//feet2 
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.fillRoundRect(181, 460, 50, 30, 20, 20);
        }

    }
}
```

See

- [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/)
- [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)
- [How to Use Buttons, Check Boxes, and Radio Buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html)
- [How to Write an Action Listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html)
- [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)

for more details

Comment: Tank You very much It helps a lot

Answer (score 0):

use the jframe class that is built in.
u can set.contentpane(visible, false) put your graphic into the content pane.
then use a jbutton to set the content pane to visible when clicked

Answer (score 0):

In order to get what you want you need both a button and a listener. You will need a `JButton` and an `ActionListener`. Below you will see some code I wrote to create a blackjack game that used `JButtons` and `ActionListeners`. The `ActionListeners` will be linked to your `JButtons` so that when the button is clicked, the `ActionListener`executes whatever you want done.

```
  JButton Quit = new JButton("Quit");
  Quit.addActionListener(new QuitListener());
  CenterSub.add(Quit, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

Let's start with the first line of the snippet. I declared a `JButton` called `Quit` on the right side of the equals. On the left side I finished the initialization and gave the `JButton` text to be displayed on the actual button. In this case the button will read `"Quit"` once the program is run. The second line adds an `ActionListener` to the `JButton` so that once the button is clicked, the code in the `ActionListener` will execute. In the parenthesis on the second line I call the new `ActionListener` `QuitListener`. When I write the Listener code, this will be its name. The last line shows where I added the button on my `JPanel`. I called the `JPanel` name (`CenterSub`), then passed in the name of the button and where I wanted it to be located as parameters.

```
private class QuitListener implements ActionListener
   {
      public  void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
      {
         System.exit(0);
      }
   }
```

This snippet is the definition for the `QuitListener` that I added to the `JButton` in the first snippet. `QuitListener` implements the interface `ActionListener` which allows me to define the `actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)` method to do what I want. The `ActionEvent` is the player clicking on the `"Quit"` button. When the button is clicked, the method `actionPerformed` will execute and call `System.exit(0)` which terminates the program, thus allowing the player to quit the game.

So, to wrap it up, to achieve what you want achieved, create a `JButton`, an `ActionListener` and in the `ActionListener` definition for the `actionEvent` method, call the paint method that you have defined. For further assistance, I highly suggest checking out the Jbutton API as well as any other APIs that you may need.

This the [`JButton` API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JButton.html).

This is my first time answering a question, so I hope this helped you gain some insight into what you need.